# -Bitcasa: Steps to detect cause and solve slow upload speed

Tags: internet-connection, isp, upload

I am using Bitcasa for backup, but with the current upload speed (<0,1 MBps), it will take over 17 consecutive days to upload 150Gb (which is the size I want to upload). I must have an upload speed of at least 2MBps (officially much more, but this is what speedtest.com shows).

If I ping, I get the following:

`--- eu1.api.bitcasa.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 51.577/78.714/151.273/29.754 ms`

About Bitcasa and my machine:

1.3 (Build 1249)
Cache Size: 2824500775.473684 (of 70168171790 free space)
ProductName:    Mac OS X 
ProductVersion: 10.7.5
BuildVersion:   11G63

How to understand the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I believe the upload speed is limited whilst you're using the machine, try to leave it alone for a few hours and see if the speed increases.  As it's an average over a period of time you should notice it improve.

Answer (score 1):

That's my traceroute

`C:>tracert eu1.api.bitcasa.com
    35 ms    40 ms    36 ms  hikhef-1-gw.ams.runnet.ru [194.85.40.241]
  6    35 ms    36 ms    36 ms  amsix01-ams1.amazon.com [195.69.146.100]
  7    62 ms    52 ms    54 ms  178.236.3.37
  8    54 ms    53 ms    53 ms  178.236.3.2
  9    53 ms    58 ms    52 ms  178.236.0.86
 10    55 ms    50 ms    53 ms  178.236.0.81
 11    53 ms    53 ms    77 ms  178.236.0.118
 12    64 ms    50 ms    50 ms  178.236.0.139
 13    52 ms    52 ms    52 ms  ec2-79-125-1-201.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [79.125.1.201]
 14     *        *        *     Timeout
 15     *        *        *     Timeout
 16     *        *        *     Timeout
 17     *        *        *     Timeout
 18     *        *        *     Timeout
 19    55 ms    50 ms    52 ms  ec2-54-195-136-203.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.195.136.203]`

So we can see that the speed problem somewhere at Amazon hosting (178.236.0.0 - 178.236.7.255 owns by Amazon Data Services Ireland).

The way to solve such speed problem - to ask Bitcasa support to kick amazon support team.
If traceroute shows the problem with your ISP - only way to call your ISP support.